# What in language, is the difference between Jaya and Vijaya?

Tags: vishnu, sanskrit

Please excuse me, I don't know much about Hinduism.
If my question is silly or offensive, I'm willing to delete it.

Starting from wikipedia, I learned about Narashima, and from that I came to hear about the Karakumas and the doorkeepers of Vishnu.

Their names are given as Jaya and Vijaya.

From what little I learned from the net, the prefix "Vi-" has some meaning, but I could not find what.

For the tags, surely someone can point me to tags that are more matching to the question. Thanks.

Comment: (Vi/वि) doesn't necessarily imply **opposites**. Technically it implies different things under different parts of speech, but here it implies **over** meaning. Follow it this way, - `Jay` (win), `Vijay` (win over win) **->** implying winner over a winner, or a very big *victory*. Similarly, `*gyaan*` (knowledge), `*vigyaan*` (knowledge over knowledge) **->** implying knowledge over knowledge, that we call *science* and so on, this is in the usual sense for very specific words that came from Sanskrit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

वि (Vi) prefix is used to either show some sort of extremeness or to show opposite-ness among other things, depending on context.

In this context, it simply means Jaya(vitory) and lots of Jaya (vijaya).

I can't be bothered to go back and look for sources in Nirukta, but I can assure you this is correct, as far as I remember the text, anyways.

You can use the [sanskrit] tag, in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Its a good question as per language. So, I will tell you difference as per hindi language.

Jaya means victory with its own boundary for example, a king defeating rebels; has attained JAYA.

Vijaya means victory outside the boundaries for example, a king defeating another king.

I hope that answers your query in terms of language.

Comment: Thank you, so from your answer I take it that it is not only the prefix that is difficult to translate exactly to english, but the very word "jaya" has no *exact* translation.